# How to restore a mock implementation between tests in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to create two tests for distinct functions in the same file.

I have `func1` that calls `func2` inside it, so I'm spying on `func2` and mocking its implementation to test `func1`, and by the end of the first test I'm restoring the mock.

The problem is that the second test fails because `func2` implementation is still mocked.

Why didn't the mock restore?

```
describe('myClass.func1', () => {
  it('returns true', async () => {
    const func2spy = jest.spyOn(myClass, 'func2').mockImplementation(() => true);
    await expect(func1()).toBe(true);
    func2spy.mockRestore();
  })
});

describe('myClass.func2', () => {
  it('returns false if argument is 0', () => {
    expect(func2(0)).toBe(false);
  })
});
```

Comment: Try to run with one worker, if you're running in parallel now

Comment: Could you perhaps give implementations for both func1 and func2?

Comment: @Razär did you get this resolved?  What does the code look like, are func1 and func2 members of a class?  (you are using an object called "myClass" for the spy)

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors, I'm sorry, I don't remember how I solved this problem but I think I've changed the approach somehow

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo works for me:

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {}

  public async func1() {
    return this.func2();
  }
  public func2(int?: number) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';

const myClass = new MyClass();

describe('MyClass.func1', () => {
  it('returns true', async () => {
    const func2Spy = jest.spyOn(myClass, 'func2').mockImplementation(() => true);
    const actualValue = await myClass.func1();
    expect(actualValue).toBeTruthy();
    func2Spy.mockRestore();
  });
});

describe('myClass.func2', () => {
  it('returns false if argument is 0', () => {
    expect(myClass.func2(0)).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/50912106/index.spec.ts
  MyClass.func1
    ✓ returns true (7ms)
  myClass.func2
    ✓ returns false if argument is 0 (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.939s, estimated 5s
```